# Отобразить список артикулов одинаковых наименований

Tags: excel, vba

У меня есть такой документ
[image: Excel]

Какую формулу необходимо поставить, что бы он получился так?
[image: Excel2]

Названий может быть и 1 и 20. Интересует как получить колонку похожие продукты. Вручную с ума сойду 10тыс. наименований редактировать. Спасибо.

Comment: А что считается похожим? Такое же название?

Comment: Да.
Например 
Носки XXS -> похожие Носки(XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL)
Носки XS-> похожие Носки(XXS, S, M, L, XL, XXL)
Вместо размеров, нужно проставить артикулы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разместить код в общем модуле:

```
Sub SimilarСode()
Dim aData(), aRes()
Dim sStr As String
Dim i As Long, n As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If i < 2 Then Exit Sub
        aData = .Range("A1:C" & i).Value
        ReDim aRes(1 To i, 1 To 1): aRes(1, 1) = "Похожие продукты"

        For i = 2 To UBound(aData)
            For n = 2 To UBound(aData)
                If aData(i, 1) = aData(n, 1) Then
                    If i <> n Then sStr = sStr & ", " & aData(n, 3)
                End If
            Next n

            aRes(i, 1) = Mid$(sStr, 3): sStr = ""
        Next i

        .Range("D1").Resize(UBound(aRes), 1).Value = aRes
    End With

    MsgBox "OK", 64, ""
End Sub
```

Запустить: поставить курсор на заголовке (или рабочей строке) кода и нажать `F5`. Если обработка не разовая, лучше создать на листе кнопку и присвоить ей запуск макроса.

Должен быть активен тот лист, на котором находится таблица с артикулами. Если по каким-либо причинам будет активен другой лист, заменить строку

```
With ActiveSheet
```

На строку с именем нужного листа:

```
With Worksheets("Лист1")
```

После обработки в столбец *D* будут выведены перечни артикулов товаров с одинаковыми названиями.

Правильнее, если столбцам *C* и *D* присвоить формат ячеек "Текстовый". Артикул - часто не число и данные будут разбросаны в ячееке влево и вправо.

Еще пример возможной ошибки - артикул с ведущими нулями "00101" в ячейке с общим форматом преобразуется в 101.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Да прибудет с тобой сила, джедай!)